# How do I get the width of the tabline in Vim script?

Tags: macvim, vim

I'm currently using `winwidth(0)` to find out how much text I can display in the tabline but this doesn't work if there are vertically split windows and the current window doesn't span the full width of the top frame. How do I get the width of the top frame or the tabline in Vim script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tabline takes *all* of the available width. The `columns` option gives you that width:

```
let tabline_width = &columns
```